# Terraform official Docker image can't see my files

Tags: docker, terraform

I'd like to use the official Hashicorp image to run Terraform rather than install manually.  I have followed the docs on dockerhub but there aren't any details about how where to mount volumes - e.g. with 'main.tf' in current directory:

```
> docker run -i -t hashicorp/terraform:light init main.tf
Terraform initialized in an empty directory!

The directory has no Terraform configuration files. You may begin working
with Terraform immediately by creating Terraform configuration files.


> docker run -i -t hashicorp/terraform:light plan main.tf
stat main.tf: no such file or directory
```

Where do I mount the files? Is there any docuementation beyond the dockerhub page that I can also use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Docker Hub docs for this image are misleading and unhelpful boilerplate, unfortunately. I would ignore them.

You need to provide the present working directory as a volume mount and you'll want to pin the version of Terraform as well as follows:

```
docker run -v `pwd`:/workspace -w /workspace hashicorp/terraform:0.12.26 init
docker run -v `pwd`:/workspace -w /workspace hashicorp/terraform:0.12.26 apply
docker run -v `pwd`:/workspace -w /workspace hashicorp/terraform:0.12.26 destroy
```

This is based on the blog post [Terraform With Docker by Victor Leong](https://web.archive.org/web/20220516223719/https://www.vic-l.com/terraform-with-docker) (sadly no longer available so I've replaced the URL with a Wayback Machine snapshot)

Comment: The link in this comment is dead.

Comment: @jdenoc thank you! I've replaced it with a link to a Wayback Machine snapshot of the original site before it disappeared.